# we are not getting all the posts from facebook

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, iphone-developer-program

This is my query for getting the post

```
 NSString *fqlquery= @"SELECT post_id,message FROM stream WHERE source_id = '100005146987508' limit 10000";
             self.newurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=%@  &access_token=%@",fqlquery,appDelegate.session.accessToken];
```

it returns

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

It seems we are not getting all the results back.  Are we doing anything wrong?

Comment: maybe access token only for Basic Permissions. Try get just Name

Comment: NSArray *permissions =
        [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream",@"offline_access",@"read_stream",@"share_item",@"publish_actions",nil];
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error)
        {
           //  [self publishStory];
    
        }];

Comment: these are the permission which i am using

Comment: and "graph.facebook.com/fql" is deprecated. Try to us actual request. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=100002032887359%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cposts.fields(id)

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this bug.
Request

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, source_id FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me()) AND source_id='xxx'
```

returns about 40 rows

Request

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, source_id FROM stream WHERE source_id='xxx'
```

returns only 2 rows

I think you'd add to limits `filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me())`